# Github: how to copy a public repo and make it updatable and private VIA BROWSER

Tags: github

In short words, I need to copy a public repo and make it private since I will add some sensitive info there, and it should be updatable when the public repo updates.

Now my method is: via browser, I'll create a repo and import git of that public repo and make it private, then I'll add sensitive info. When the public repo updates, I delete my private repo and create again...... The pros of the method is I could give a name to the repo.

Is there any quicker way?

Comment: "I want to do common things with a git repository but I'm too lazy to learn basic git commands" is not a valid question. `git merge` is your friend, but if you don't want to use it, then you have no other options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any quicker way?

Yes. Keep two remotes, the public repo and the private repo. From time to time, pull from the public repo and push to the private repo.

> I don't want to install git

Well, if this is github, just fork the public repo. But in my opinion refusing to install git is just silly.

Comment: Thanks. I've installed git long time ago and forget everything I've learnd. At first I've tried the method of forking but I cann't make it private.

Comment: Understood, sorry about that part.